# Form error states not updating after chrome autofill - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In AngularJS, form error states like `loginForm.password.$invalid`, `loginForm.password.$pristine` not updating for password after chrome autofill but *updating correctly for username textbox*. Password error states are updating correctly after clicking somewhere in the page or keypressing. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

```
<form name="loginForm" novalidate>
   <input type="text" ng-change="onUserTyping()" class="form-control" ng-minlength="4" maxlength="25" autocomplete="on" ng-model="credentials.username" id="username" name="username" required />

   <input type="password" ng-change="onUserTyping()" class="form-control" ng-minlength="6" autocomplete="off" ng-model="credentials.password" id="password" name="password" required />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it could be because you have autocomplete="off" on password

Comment: I tried by setting autocomplete to "on". Still not working. Is there any solution to fix this problem?

Comment: are you getting consoled password? at that time when form submitting ?

Comment: @JigarPrajapati Password states are still updating correctly after clicking somewhere or keypressing. I think the password states need a refresh by writing some code.